How i can change color of open date picker button?
import React from 'react'
import { DesktopDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';

function DatePicker() {
    return (
        <DesktopDatePicker
            slotProps={{
                textField: {
                    variant: 'filled',
                    focused: true,
                    color: 'secondary',
                    sx: { mb: 3, ml: 5, color: 'red' }
                }
            }}
        />
    )
}

export default DatePicker

i want to change color of icon that opens date picker, but i dont know how to do

You can use the prop called renderInput that simplifies usingnon-Material UI text field input components:
https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/pickers-migration/#render-input
inside it you will write a component that renders a TextField that spreads existing parameters and uses the prop SX to style the custom field.
your code should look like this:
<DesktopDatePicker
      label="Select Date"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Select Date"
          variant="filled"
          color="secondary"
          sx={{
            mb: 3,
            ml: 5,
            '& .MuiIconButton-root': { 
              color: 'red',
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    />


<DesktopDatePicker
  label="Select Date"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Select Date"
      variant="filled"
      color="secondary"
      sx={{
        mb: 3,
        ml: 5,
        '& .MuiIconButton-root': { 
          color: 'red',
        }
      }}
    />
  )}
/>


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
